$\mathrm{SO}(3)$-invariant polynomials
The Lie group $\mathrm{SO}(3,\mathbb{R})$ has a representation $V_l$ of dimension $2l+1$ for each $l=0,1,\ldots$
I am looking for a single polynomial in $\mathbb{R}[V_l]$ which is invariant under the $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ action. The obvious example for $l=1$ is
$$x^2+y^2+z^2$$
This is a duplicate of this 2017 MSE question and the answer there is helpful but only partial.
Unless I'm mistaken, $\mathrm{SO}(3,\mathbb{R})$-invariance should boil down to $\mathrm{SU}(2)$-invariance, and thus to $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$-invariance. This (under the guise of binary forms) has been studied for over 100 years and people apparently have found (minimal) generators of invariants of $k[\mathrm{Sym}^n(k^2)]$ for up to $n=8$, maybe further. But I'm not asking for a full set of generators, I just want one (nonconstant) polynomial for each $n$.
Edit: I'm clarifying the action of $\mathrm{SO}(3,\mathbb{R})$ on $\mathbb{R}^{l+1}$ for the benefit of a commenter below. I also provide a nontrivial example for $l=2$.
The action of $\mathrm{SO}(3,\mathbb{R})$ on $\mathbb{R}^{2l+1}$ has been known for a very long time. The idea is that there's a map $\mathrm{SU}(2)\rightarrow \mathrm{SO}(3,\mathbb{R})$ with kernel $I, -I$, so any irreducible representation of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ where $-I$ acts trivially (namely, the irreps of odd dimension) will descend to a representation of $\mathrm{SO}(3,\mathbb{R})$. The simplest way of realizing this representation is in terms of harmonic polynomials. Note that $\mathrm{SO}(3)\subset \mathrm{GL}(3)$ acts naturally on $\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]_l$, the space of homogeneous polynomials of degree $l$. Let $\mathfrak{h}_3^l$ be the $2l+1$-dimensional vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]_l$ consisting of the degree $l$ harmonic polynomials. This is defined as the kernel of the Laplacian $\Delta=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}+ \frac{\partial}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial}{\partial z^2}$. The subspace $\mathfrak{h}_3^l$ is preserved by the action of $\mathrm{SO}(3,\mathbb{R})$ because the elements of $\mathrm{SO}(3,\mathbb{R})$ commute with the Laplacian.
Finally, my question:

$\mathrm{SO}(3,\mathbb{R})$ acts on
$\mathbb{R}[\mathfrak{h}_3^l]$. I seek a polynomial in this space
which is fixed by the action (it is known to exist!).

Example for $l=1$: the vector space $\mathfrak{h}_3^1$ is spanned by the polynomials $p_1=x,p_2=y,p_3=z$ (they are all killed by the Laplacian). Now $\mathbb{R}[\mathfrak{h}_3^1]=\mathbb{R}[p_1,p_2,p_3]$ and there is an obvious $\mathrm{SO}(3,\mathbb{R})$-invariant polynomial of degree $2$: $p_1^2+p_2^2+p_3^2$.
Example for $l=2$: the vector space $\mathfrak{h}_3^2$ is spanned by the polynomials $p_1=x^2-y^2$, $p_2=y^2-z^2$, $q_1=yz$, $q_2=xz$, $q_3=xy$. Now consider the algebra $\mathbb{R}[\mathfrak{h}_3^2]=\mathbb{R}[p_1,p_2,q_1,q_2,q_3]$. A quick calculation shows that the polynomial $f:=p_1^2+p_1p_2+p_2^2+3(q_1^2+q_2^2+q_3^2)$ is $\mathrm{SO}(3,\mathbb{R})$-invariant.
Can anyone give such a polynomial for arbitrary $l$? Please note that the realization of $V_l$ as $\mathfrak{h}_3^l$ is not strictly necessary, and an intrinsic description would probably be better.

$\newcommand{\i}{\mathrm{i}}$
$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$
This necessarily is eventually the same as the purely algebraic answer, but the map
$$p\mapsto\int_{S^2}\frac{\d\Omega_x}{4\pi}p(x)^2$$
that takes a harmonic polynomial of degree $l$ to the average of its square over the unit sphere is, by construction, a rotation-invariant positive-definite quadratic form on harmonic polynomials of degree $l$.

In full detail: define a basis for the complex harmonic polynomials
$\Upsilon_{\ell}^m(x,y,z)$ by the Herglotz expansion
$$\exp(
  x(\tfrac{v^2-u^2}{2})
  -\i y(\tfrac{u^2+v^2}{2})
  +zuv)
  =\sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell}
    \Upsilon_{\ell}^m(x,y,z)
      \tfrac{u^{l+m}}{(l+m)!}
      \tfrac{v^{l-m}}{(l-m)!}\text{.}$$
Then $\Upsilon_{\ell}^{-m}=(-1)^m(\Upsilon_{\ell}^m)^{*}$, so define the
basis for the real harmonic polynomials $\Upsilon_{\ell m}$ via
$$\Upsilon_{\ell}^m =(-1)^m(\Upsilon_{\ell m} + \i \Upsilon_{\ell(-m)})
\quad$$
for $m>0$, with $\Upsilon_{\ell 0}=\Upsilon_{\ell}^0$. Then classically it has
been known that the $\Upsilon_{\ell m}$ are orthogonal, and
$$\int_{S^2}\frac{\d\Omega}{4\pi}(\Upsilon_{\ell 0})^2
=\frac{(\ell!)^2}{2\ell+1}$$
$$\int_{S^2}\frac{\d\Omega}{4\pi}(\Upsilon_{\ell m})^2
=\frac{(\ell+m)!(\ell-m)!}{2(2\ell+1)}$$
so that the map
$$\sum_{m=-\ell}^{\ell}a_{m}\Upsilon_{\ell m}
\mapsto \frac{(\ell!)^2}{2\ell+1}a_0^2 +
\sum_{m=1}^{\ell}\frac{(\ell+m)!(\ell-m)!}{2(2\ell+1)}(a_m^2 + a_{-m}^2)
$$
is an invariant nondegenerate quadratic form on harmonic polynomials of degree $\ell$.
Dualizing with respect to it and rescaling, it must be that
$$Q_{\ell}(\Upsilon)=\binom{2\ell}{\ell}\Upsilon_{\ell 0}^2
+2\sum_{m=1}^{\ell}\binom{2\ell}{\ell+m}(\Upsilon_{\ell m}^2
+\Upsilon_{\ell(-m)}^2)$$
is an invariant element of the second symmetric power of the harmonic
polynomials.

Thank you for the added detail! This looks really good, and gives an actual answer.

For $F$ a binary form of even degree $n=2\ell$ (what you need given the $SO(3)$ motivation), take $(F,F)_{n}$ the transvectant of $F$ with itself of order $n$.
See this MO answer for a definition
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439980/exterior-products-of-irreducible-representations-of-sl-2c/439991#439991
Also note that, in order to convert this in $SO(3)$ language, $F$ is the same as a harmonic homogeneous polynomial of degree $\ell$ in three variables. The invariant is up to scale the complete index contraction between two copies of the corresponding symmetric tensor. Namely, it the symmetric tensor is $C_{i_1,\ldots,i_{\ell}}$ with indices in $\{1,2,3\}$, i.e., if the harmonic polynomial is
$$
\sum_{i_1,\ldots,i_{\ell}=1}^{3} C_{i_1,\ldots,i_{\ell}} x_{i_1}\cdots x_{i_{\ell}}
$$
the invariant is
$$
\sum_{i_1,\ldots,i_{\ell}=1}^{3} (C_{i_1,\ldots,i_{\ell}})^2
$$

Thank you for your answer. I'm still trying to parse it. In an example, if I take the $2$-trasvectant of an arbitrary $F=\alpha x^2+\beta xy+\gamma y^2$ with itself, I get the (discriminant?) $8\alpha\gamma-2\beta^2$. How do I recover the invariant function $x^2+y^2+z^2$ from this?

You will not be able to recover this invariant because you and @Abdelmalek Abdesselam  are talking about different $SO(3)$ actions. See the updating to my answer.

@Leox I disagree

@AlvaroMartinez: the relation between the binary form and the harmonic polynomial perspective is not immediate but it is explained in section 1.4 of the thesis by Marc Olive https://hal.science/tel-03399808/document

I explained how to get the invariant by first finding the tensor C. It's not a good idea to use x,y,z instead of $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$. Also you get in trouble by writing a basis p,q etc of the space of harmonic polynomials because the invariant i gave is just the restriction to the harmonic subspace of an invariant for arbitrary homogeneous polynomials of that degree.

@AbdelmalekAbdesselam Thank you for your answer. I saw you linked his thesis somewhere else, but I haven't been able to locate it (link is broken)

I think the link is not broken but the website is very slow responding for some reason. I managed to download the pdf a couple hours ago after letting the page load for quite some while.

It worked for me now! I will try and figure this out and accept your answer

The Lie algebra $so(3)$ act on the polynomials of $3$-variavles  $x,y,z$  by the derivations
$$
 x \frac{\partial}{\partial y}-y \frac{\partial}{\partial x},x \frac{\partial}{\partial z}-z \frac{\partial}{\partial x}, y \frac{\partial}{\partial z}-z \frac{\partial}{\partial y}.
$$
So, all invariants of the action is the solutions of the following system of differential equation
$$
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle x \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}-y \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0,\\
\displaystyle x \frac{\partial u}{\partial z}-z \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0,\\
 \displaystyle y \frac{\partial u }{\partial z}-z \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0.
\end{cases}
$$
It is not hard to see that the general solution of the system has the form $F(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ where $F$ is any one variable polynomial.
Therefore the $SO(3)$-invariant polynomials exists only for even degrees, for example $$ (x^2+y^2+z^2)^n, n=1,2, \ldots$$
P.S. The question is incorrectly formulated; the author confuses two different $SO(3)$ actions. Schematically, the situation is described as follows. Let the group $G$ act on the vector space $V$. Then $v \in V$ is called $G$-invariant if $g v = v$ for all $g \in G$.
Another type of invariance arises if we consider the induced action of $G$ on the algebra of polynomial functions $k[V]$, specifically $(gf)(v) = f(g^{-1}v)$. A polynomial function $f$ is called invariant if $gf = f, \forall g \in G$.
Returning to the group $SO(3)$. It acts by substitutions on the algebra of polynomials $k[x, y, z]$. This representation is a direct sum of vector spaces of polynomials of fixed degree. With respect to this action, there is only one invariant $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$.
However, considering invariants in the algebra of polynomial functions, the situation is quite different. The algebra of such  $SO(3, \mathbb{C})$- invariants is indeed isomorphic to the algebra of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$- invariants, and we can use the results of the classical invariant theory . The simplest way to obtain invariants in this case is to compute the discriminant of the binary form of degree $n$ for each $n$.
You need to specify which type of invariance you are referring.

The question is clear for the action of $SO(3)$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$. The result I'm looking for is for the action of $SO(3)$ on $\mathbb{R}^{2l+1}$.

@Alvaro Martinez Ок, then define the action

It should be somewhere in Fulton-Harris https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387974954

@ Alvaro Martinez. No, there is no action of $SO(3)$ on $\mathbb{R}^{2l+1}$ in this book. Provide a precise definition of how $SO(3)$ acts on $\mathbb{R}^{2l+1}$. I doubt such an action exists at all. For example, explain how $SO(3)$ acts on the variables $t, s$ in the vector $(x, y, z, t, s) \in \mathbb{R}^{5}$.

I'm afraid you're confidently incorrect
